# Rails 3 form_for action with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

```
<%  form_for [commentable, Comment.new], :action => 'create', :remote => false do |f|%>
<%=f.hidden_field :commentable_id, :value=> commentable.id %><br/>
<%=f.hidden_field :parent_id, :value=>1 %><br/>
```

And a controller:

```
def create(commentable)
@commentable = commentable.find(params[:comment][:commentable_id])
```

How I can pass commentable type to a create action in my for_for?
Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to reshape your question if you want further assistence, can you share more about your code?

Comment: in your controller, try `@commentable = Commentable.create(params[:comment][:commentable_id])`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
commentable.class
```

Along the lines of what you already did you can use a hidden field:

```
<%=f.hidden_field :commentable_type, :value=> commentable.class %><br/>
```

Then in controller:

```
@commentable = Object.const_get(params[:comment][:commentable_type]).find(params[:comment][:commentable_id])
```

Comment: Thanks, but how I can pass my commentable object to create action?

Comment: Why pass the entire object? You can just pass an id and fetch the object later.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass a object explicitly to you create method in controller, if you have commentable model:

```
def create
  @commentable = Commentable.find(params[:comment][:commentable_id])
  #more code
end
```

Note capital C in Commentable.

Comment: Sure, but I use acts_as_commentable_with_threading, and Commentable class doesn't exists.